# Generating Invoice Number

Tags: laravel-5.8

I am using a separate table to generate invoice numbers.

The code i am using is :

```
Branch::where('id', $branch_id)->update([
    'piref' => DB::raw('piref+1')
    ]);
$piref = Branch::where('id', $branch_id)->get('piref');
$piref = $piref[0]['piref'];
```

My question is if the code is wrapped in a transaction. Is this approach safe ?
I tried to use Laravel Increments() but it does not return the newly generated number.

Answer (score 0):

Model method `increment()` increments property of model and column value in database.

```
$branch = Branch::find($branch_id);
$branch->increment('piref');
$piref = $branch->piref;
```